# Problems running code

Tags: java

I am fairly new to this site, and I need some help on this program I am working on for practice. I am trying to run an 'if-else' program that asks for the radius or diameter and then outputs the circumference. I've gotten to a pretty basic start, but even whilst looking all over the internet for answers, I'm still confused.

here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Circumference
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double radius;
    double diameter;
    double c1 = (3.14 * (radius * radius));
    double c2 = (3.14 * diameter);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String answer = String.valueOf(1);

    System.out.println("Do you have the radius, y/n?");
    answer = in.nextLine();
    {
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Then give me the radius");
            float radius = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Circumference is : " + c1);
            {
                else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                {
                    System.out.println("Do you know the diameter then, y/n?");
                    string answer = in.nextLine();
                    {
                        else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                        {
                            System.out.println("Then input the diameter");
                            float diameter = in.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Circumference is : " + c2);
                            {
                                else if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Then find it");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to change the string, it won't recognize it and say "can't change string to int", or that the radius in "c1" can't be found when executed.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I "think" you need to understand how `if-else` statements work

Comment: Also, you can't compute `c1` and `c2` without first getting the input (diameter and radius) from the user.

Comment: I "think" you also need to understand how variables are declared in Java.

Comment: Umm surely this code doesn't even compile?!?!

Comment: Would I have to do "c1 * (radius * radius)" in the "System.out.println", instead of declaring it in the beginning ?

Like I said, I'm fairly new.

Comment: We understand you're fairly new but this is the wrong place to learn Java.

Answer (score 0):

By looking through your code it is very clear you are extremely new to java.
Like @m0skit0 said:

> We understand you're fairly new but this is the wrong place to learn Java.

Your understanding of basic conventions of java is fundamentally flawed, for example the concept of if/else and variable declaring/initializing. I recommend you talk to your professor or whoever it is who is teaching you java. The program you supplied doesn't compile properly at all. Compiler errors should be very simple to fix because most IDEs basically fix them for you...
Here are some things you must fix for this to work:

In line 19: `float radius = in.nextInt();`
Here you are declaring and initializing a float called radius, but you already have a double called radius. You cannot have to variables of the same name in java.

In line 21: For some reason unknown to me you are inserting a `{` that is never closed. That brace serves no purpose and is redundant.

In line 22: You cant have an else without an if.

In line 25: `String` is a class and therefore capitalized, unlike in C. Why are you creating a new String called answer when you already declared one? Once again you cannot have to variables of the same name.

In line 26: Another totally unnecessary curly brace.

In line 30: For the third time, you cannot have multiple variables named the same thing.

In line 32: Another totally useless brace.

In line 33: You cant have an else without an if.

Comment: I knew that I would criticism over the code I've compiled, and I'm happy to hear that. I also know this isn't the place to learn java but I just wanted to know how this piece of code could be fixed so I can be able to build from this because I'm just starting to get more into learning java. Thank you! (P.S. I'm using textwrangler to create this, but I really should be using something else :/ )

Comment: @Testrun12 No problem :) I recommend you use eclipse instead of text wrangler - itll make your life so much easier

Comment: Yeah. My class is using textwrangler and it's a pain to not even know what is wrong half the time